# Distance of a Quantum Error Correcting Code

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Consider an $[n,1,d]$ quantum code.  Let the weight of any operator $E$ be the number of coordinates in the tensor product space that the operator acts on nontrivially (for example, $X \otimes X \otimes I^{\otimes{n-2}}$ has weight $2$).  The standard definition of the distance of a quantum code is the following: a quantum code spanned by $0_L$ and $1_L$ has distance $d$ if for any operator $E$ of weight $d$,

$$\langle i_L|E|j_L\rangle = c_E \delta_{ij}.$$

In the case of stabilizer codes, this reduces to saying that the minimal weight of (any representative  of the) logical operators $X_L,Z_L$ is $d$, so that these operators are representative of the minimal weight actions that can perturb the code space.

I might be missing some simple observation, but are there examples of any codes such that both $X_L$ and $Z_L$ are weight $d$, yet there exists some smaller error operator (say weight $1$) so that $\langle 0_L |E|1_L \rangle \neq 0$?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the $[[5,1,3]]$ qubit code, e.g., chapter 7.10 [here](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph229/notes/chap7.pdf).

Comment: Your definition is wrong. Distance is the least $ d $ such that there exists an error $ E $ of weight $ d $  for which it is not the case that $ <i_L|E|j_L>=c_E \delta_{ij} $. As an example consider the $ [[7,1,3]] $ code, which of course has distance 3. This code has distance 3 because $ E=XXXIIII $ is a weight 3 error for which $ <i_L|E|j_L> \neq c_E \delta_{ij} $ in particular $ <0_L|E|1_L>=1 \neq 0 $. In particular $ XXXIIII $ is a weight 3 representative of logical bit flip $ X_L $.  For a stabilizer code $ d $ is always the minimal weight of an error that represents a logical Pauli.

Comment: For a reference with the correct definition see for example https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/what-does-quantum-error-correction-code-notation-stand-for